# jquery not() function not cooperating with serialize() function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use serialize to spit out a text string of the data in an html form.  However, under certain conditions, I want to exclude form elements from the string.  I thought the 'not()' function in jquery would be the right tool but am having trouble.

Here is my code snippet ... note that the console is outputting a string that includes the "setType".   I have tried changing the not to be `not($("setType"))` and other permutations... with no luck.

```js
data = $('#setAtributesForm').not("#setType").serialize();
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <form id='setAtributesForm'>
            <label for="setType">Select set type:</label>
            <select id="setType" name="setType">
                <option value="EDI">EDI</option>
                <option value="EWI">EWI</option>
                <option value="EWI">Other</option>
            </select>
            <label for="containersQuantity">Number of containers:</label>
            <input type="number" name="containersQuantity" id="containersQuantity"
            min="1" max="40" value="1"/>
    <!-- snip for brevity sake -->
     </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('#setAtributesForm')` selects the form, which is not `#setType` so the entire form is serialized ignoring the `not` filter.

You can try to select all the `input` elements then then exclude the target element and serialize

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var data = $('#setAtributesForm :input').not("#setType").serialize();
  console.log(data)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id='setAtributesForm'>
  <label for="setType">Select set type:</label>
  <select id="setType" name="setType">
    <option value="EDI">EDI</option>
    <option value="EWI">EWI</option>
    <option value="EWI">Other</option>
  </select>
  <label for="containersQuantity">Number of containers:</label>
  <input type="number" name="containersQuantity" id="containersQuantity" min="1" max="40" value="1" />
  <!-- snip for brevity sake -->
</form>
<button>Test</button>
```